# jQuery Datepicker - Limit minDate according to previous calendar

Tags: jquery, calendar

I have 2 datepickers as following:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker1, #datepicker2" ).datepicker({
    minDate: 'today',
    maxDate: "+90D",
    showOn: "button",
    buttonImage: "images/calendar.gif",
    buttonImageOnly: true,
    dateFormat: "D, dd MM, yy"
    });
});
```

I want `datepicker2` have the minimumdate value selected in the first calendar + 1 day.(i.e. if first calendar date was May 16th, 2nd calendar should have the min date set to May 17th)

Answer (score 12):

I had the same scenario. What I did was to set the minDate value of the second datepicker in the "select" event handler of the first datepicker. Worked like a charm.

EDIT: Here is an example:

```
$("#datepicker1").datepicker({
    //normal setup parameters here
    onSelect: function (dateValue, inst) {
        $("#datepicker2").datepicker("option", "minDate", dateValue)
    }
});
```

Comment: just pass date like function(date){

Answer (score 2):

Detailed answers here don't really answer the question, which was "how do I set the minDate of the second datepicker, on the value of the first datepicker + 1 DAY" ?

It might be too late for you but since I quite struggled to find a solution, here it is :

```
$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker1" ).datepicker({
        minDate: 'today',
        maxDate: "+90D",
        showOn: "button",
        buttonImage: "images/calendar.gif",
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        dateFormat: "D, dd MM, yy"
        onClose: function(selectedDate, inst) {
            var selected_date = new Date(inst.selectedYear, inst.selectedMonth, inst.selectedDay);
            new_date = new Date(selected_date.getTime() + 86400000);
            new_date = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('dd/mm/yy', new_date);
            $( "#datepicker2" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", new_date);
  }
    });
});
```

**Explanations :**

You have to get a Date object from the datepicker1 field, with Year, Month, Day.

Then, you call this Date object and transform it into a UNIX Timestamp, to which you add 86400000 (number of microseconds in one day). Which gives you a new Date object.

After that, you format the Date object you just created to the correct display (which may not be the one presented in this answer), by calling `formatDate` method of jQuery DatePicker API.

In the end, you apply the minDate of your datepicker2 field with your new_date.

Comment: What is the difference between this and tobias86's answer? It looks like you're using different event handlers but doing the same basic thing.

Comment: Tobias86's answer sets the minDate of the second field to the same date as the first field selected date. Whereas my answer sets the minDate of the second field as the first field selected date + 1 day.

Comment: Gotcha, if you take the date passed into the `onClose` event handler you can do this with less code: `$( "#datepicker2" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", new Date(selectedDate.getTime() + 86400000))`. This adds one day onto the selected date, note that JS time-stamps are down to the millisecond.

Comment: maxDate: "+90D",  that helped me out

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the range example: http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#date-range

Comment: $(function() {
  $( "#datepicker, #datepicker1, #datepicker2, #datepicker3, #datepicker4, #datepicker5, #datepicker6" ).datepicker({
  minDate: 'today',
  maxDate: "+90D",
  showOn: "button",
  buttonImage: "images/calendar.gif",
  buttonImageOnly: true,
  dateFormat: "D, dd MM, yy"
  });
 });

Comment: Actually I have 7 datepickers....I just reduced the question!!!! I want each datepicker mindate should be +1 than previous datepickers minDAte....$(function() {
  $( "#datepicker, #datepicker1, #datepicker2, #datepicker3, #datepicker4, #datepicker5, #datepicker6" ).datepicker({
  minDate: 'today',
  maxDate: "+90D",
  showOn: "button",
  buttonImage: "images/calendar.gif",
  buttonImageOnly: true,
  dateFormat: "D, dd MM, yy"
  });
 });

Comment: As you can see in the src of the example implement your requirements in `onSelect: function( selectedDate )`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend the DateRange Picker from Filament Group: http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/date_range_picker_using_jquery_ui_16_and_jquery_ui_css_framework/

I've used it in the past and it's a breeze to set up.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution. In this context I am using "Date From" and "Date To" as default text in datepicker.

```
$(function () {
        $("#DateFrom").datepicker({

            maxDate: new Date(new Date($('#DateTo').val()).valueOf()),
            beforeShow: function () {
                if ($("#DateFrom").val() == "Date From" && $("#DateTo").val() == "Date To") {
                    $("#DateFrom").datepicker('option', { minDate: null, maxDate: null });
                }

            },
            onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
                var currentDate = new Date(dateText);
                var valueofcurrentDate = currentDate.valueOf();
                var newDate = new Date(valueofcurrentDate);
                $("#DateTo").datepicker("option", "minDate", newDate);


            }

        });

        $("#DateTo").datepicker({

            minDate: new Date(new Date($('#DateTo').val()).valueOf()),
            beforeShow: function () {
                if ($("#DateFrom").val() == "Date From" && $("#DateTo").val() == "Date To") {
                    $("#DateTo").datepicker('option', { minDate: null, maxDate: null });
                }

            },
            onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
                var currentDate = new Date(dateText);
                var valueofcurrentDate = currentDate.valueOf();
                var newDate = new Date(valueofcurrentDate);
                $("#DateFrom").datepicker("option", "maxDate", newDate);



            }

        });



 //checking for key combinations which are allowed

        $("#DateFrom").keypress(function (e) {
            switch (e.keyCode) {
                case 46:  // delete                      
                case 8:  // backspace                       
                    break;
                default:
                    e.preventDefault();
                    break;
            }
        });

        $("#DateTo").keypress(function (e) {
            switch (e.keyCode) {
                case 46:  // delete                      
                case 8:  // backspace                      
                    break;
                default:
                    e.preventDefault();
                    break;
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You must initialize both datepicker.

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
    var dateToday=new Date();
    $("#datepicker2").datepicker();
    $("#datepicker1").datepicker({  
      minDate: dateToday,   
      onSelect:function(ui, event) { $('#datepicker2').datepicker("option","minDate",ui);}  
      });
});
```

Comment: Please provide some details to your answer.

Comment: Which type of details you need?

Answer (score 0):

Try this : works fine for me

```
$("#datepicker1").datepicker({
    //normal setup parameters here
    onSelect: function(date) {
              var           minDateObject= new Date();//compose the date you want to set
          $( "#datepicker2" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate",minDateObject );
    }   
   });
```

Hope will be Helpful.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("#txtStartDate").datepicker({
    //pick the first date and must not max today
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        changeYear: true,
        maxDate: '+0D', 
    onSelect: function (dateValue){
        //onselect set the min of txtEndDate to be the current txtStartDate value
        $("#txtEndDate").datepicker({ 
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        changeYear: true,
        minDate: dateValue,
        maxDate: '+0D', 
    });
    }
});
});
```